# multi store with different payment gateways and owners? Magento or Pretashop

Tags: magento, prestashop, multistore

I need to use a eCommerce for create a website (big store).

All products must be listed in this website, but the products are differents shops, owners that have differents payment gateways.

I need to manage sales that all stores in my backend.

Is it possible with Magento or Prestashop by a native way.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is equal to 'is better Intel or AMD' :). However, from 1.5, PrestaShop has the multishop feature, native obviously. One installation, more shops.

Comment: But, is it possible that each shop have a diferrent payment gateway, and the products of all shops haven been listed in a main shop?

Comment: If the modules are developed for multishop, yes. You configure the products that will displayed on each shop.